# Debugging OpenCL with Intel SDK for visual studio dont stop at breakpoints

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, opencl

I want to debug my OpenCL Code via Intel SDK and visual studio 2013, but the debugger don't stop at the breakpoints.
I enabled OpenCL Kernel debugging and set the buildoption to -g -s  and added a breakpoint in the opencl code (I also do't use any offset).

I've also tried all the voodoo mentioned elsewhere including.

- Setting a breakpoint at (/behind) the creation of the context.*
- Using only Visual Studio Instance the same time
- spitting three times beyond the left shoulder before starting debugging
- ...

but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

*This leads to the following, before reaching the breakpoint the OCL-Breakpoints are marked as non-reachable and afterwards they are shown reachable with file and line of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which Device do you use for debug?
Only intel CPU is allowed for debugging with intel SDK.
intel graphics wont work.

Check the following:
Do you use the intel compiler instead of MSVC compiler?
right click the project -> convert to opencl project / use intel c++ compiler

Compiler settings:
Code_builder menue -> opencl debugger -> options

check "enable opencl kernel debugging"
specify a work item you want to debug (0,0,0 is fine and the frist thread if you only use a global workgrp size and no local)

tab api debugger: check enable opencl api debugger

after -g -s you must add the path to the kernel like:

```
options = " -g -s E:\\prog\\clproj\\Clproj\\kernel.cl";
```

Did you hand over the options char* to the clBuildProgram like this?

```
clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, options, NULL, NULL);
```

Make sure you use the intel opencl libs and not any other opencl libs.

For correct setup with Vstudio look here:

[intel guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/opencl/user-guide/index.htm#Configuring_Microsoft_Visual_Studio.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when trying to debug OpenCL kernels using mixed platforms (C# with C|C++). When my test project is a C# project that calls native C|C++ libraries (the OpenCL code resides there) the Intel OpenCL Debugger was disabled. I couldn't manage to make it work for mixed platforms.

The workaround was to get rid of the C# project and use only native code. For unit testing it is acceptable, but one could imagine that the OpenCL code should be integrated in a system mainly developed under C#. Up to date I couldn't find any working solution to debug OpenCL code on such systems.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the same problem - although I had everything mentioned in the above contributions correctly configured:

I created a new project with the "CodeBuilder Project for Windows"-template from Intel  (Installed\Templates\Visual C++\OpenCL) and copied my contents into this new project.

After this the breakpoints got hit.

Comment: Same issue, followed every step and still does not work. Did you solve it or not?